# Laplace Transform for a trig function

Tags: laplace-transform

Help me finding the Laplace Transform using trig identities for:
t sin(2t) sin(5t)

this is what I've got so far:$\frac{1}{4i}[(s-7i)^{-2} + (s+7i)^{-2} - (s-3i)^{-2} - (s+3i)^{-2}]$
[image: My Solution steps]

Comment: Do you get $4i$ by the multiplication of $2i*2i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with that:

$$sin(2t)sin(5t)=\frac{1}{2}[cos(3t)-cos(7t)]$$

- From: $sin(\alpha)sin(\beta)=\frac{1}{2}[cos(\alpha-\beta)-cos(\alpha+\beta)]$
- After you can use this property: $\mathscr{L}[tf(t)]=-\frac{dF(s)}{ds}$

Comment: That's pretty much what they did, using complex exponentials.

Comment: @Ryan Reich: Sure, but, in this case you have to solve just $\mathscr{L}[tcos(t)]$ that you can solve immediately with the correlated property (I added it to the answer)